# Disable SVG drag

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I would like to disable drag and drop on this SVG element, but failed with several tries,

```
/// Define drag beavior
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", dragmove);

function dragmove(d) {
    // if the event.x goes over a boundry, trigger "dragend"
    if(d3.event.x > 200){
        //drag.dragend(); 
        drag.trigger("dragend");
    }

  var x = d3.event.x;
  var y = d3.event.y;
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
}

svgContainer.call(drag);
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nhe613kt/76/

I want disable drag on my chart or matrix you can say, I want it fixed and zoom able.

I am following this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/typeofgraphic/Ne8h2/4/ but it doesn't has any method

drag.dragend(); 
  //drag.trigger("dragend");

Exception here as it throws - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: why dont you just not call the drag on the SVG ? Or are you trying to set a boundary for the drag  ?

Comment: How come youre calling 'zoom' twice on your SVG container ? Also, its your zoom function thats giving you the drag capability not your drag functions.

Comment: If I remove one of the zoom, it stops working, so not sure why

Comment: remove the first one as the second one works. This is because zoom is not created until after the first one so the first call doesnt know what zoom is. Because it's a variable it has to be created before you call it. If you put it as a function you can put it anywhere :))

Comment: what is your end goal ? What is it you want to do by disabling the panning ?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed you drag capability. You had two zoom variables, the first one called zoomed which was also a variable but wasn't declared until after it was called which wouldn't work. Also called your zoom variable as soon as you made your SVG. Yours was jittery as you appended a 'g' element after you made the SVG and then called your zoom so your zoom was being put on the 'g' element inside your SVG not on your actual SVG.

JSFiddle update : http://jsfiddle.net/nhe613kt/90/

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
           .call(zoom) //called earlier
           .attr("width", width)
           .attr("height", height)
           .style("background-color", "black")
           .append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")");
```

Like mentioned in the comments, whats your end goal ? How come you want to disable your drag ? Do you wish to drag each rectangle individually ? If so you'll have to call the drag on each individual rectangle :) Tell me what else you want it to do and ill give it a go :)